# Serialization of compiled code

Tags: c#, serialization, compilation

A question I can't figure out, I am having fun with a little tool that I am making, the idea is that I allow the user that he/she writes his/her own C# code, and I save that code into a DB, once they wish to run that script I simply execute the following code:

```
 var Script = CSharpScript.Create<string>(ScriptText, options, typeof(Script_Host));
 var _Compilation = Script.Compile();

 ScriptRunner<string> runner = Script.CreateDelegate();

 Script_Host globals = new Script_Host();
 globals._Parent = this;
 globals._ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
 globals.Source = Source;
 globals.Destination = Destination;
 globals.Parameters = Parameters;
 globals.Result = "";
 _ScriptResult = runner(globals).Result;
 Result = _ScriptResult;
```

So I have compiled the code and it's runnable and it works, and that is great, but it has a flaw. It means every time a user wants to run the code I have to take that piece of code, compile it and run it ... this takes time.

Now I simply want to take that `compiled` code, serialize it and insert it into a DB as varbinary ... so each script gets compiled only once (or more if they are doing an update) and that's it..

What is best way to reach for the `compiled` script, how can I convert it to varbinary?

Comment: Compile it to an assembly and store it locally? Generate a hash to determine if you already have a compiled version available.

Comment: You could compile your code once, write result to a temp location and use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` to get generated assembly as byte array. Then, save it to ddbb using a blob column.

Comment: @Oscar thanks for direction, but here is where I have a problem `write result to a temp location` ... in my variable `_Compilation` is where I have compiled code, right? type of `_Compilation' is System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic>` , when I check it using break point, it's empty ... so my main problem is that I can't figure out what exactly to write to temp location

Comment: @Veljko89 Well, I don't know how to do it with CSharpScript class, but you maybe could swith to classes in Microsoft.CSharp and System.CodeDom.Compiler namespaces. See:  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job.
Scripting is about "quickly executing a string of code" if you want to dynamically make assemblies and keep them around a standard compilation process is the better way to go ...

Executing a simple script:

```
await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("Console.WriteLine(\"Hello world!\")");
```

Creating assemblies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/generating-and-compiling-source-code-from-a-codedom-graph

... the result here is that you end up with a physical assembly you can reuse not a context based on the fly generated blob of script in ram.